# Default editor for git set to nano--how?

Tags: vim, git

New eoan installation, just installed git and vim and recovered one of my projects from backup. Configured git user.email and user.name, made a couple of small changes, tried commit and... nano started. It took me some time to understand how to exit it without committing (BTW I use vim). Neither VISUAL nor EDITOR are set, and the git guide says

> By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor via one of the shell environment variables `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`, or else falls back to the `vi` editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages.

(https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Well, I set EDITOR=vi in my profile, but I'd like to understand what's going on here. Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My wild guess you have set nano as a default system editor, but you can try to update it with

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: Yup, that's it--and that's exactly what I wanted to check, to avoid other similar surprises. Many thanks!

Comment: (anyway I didn't set it, I just found it set that way after a minimal installation...)

Answer (score 19):

You are missing `GIT_EDITOR` and `core.editor`.

> **ENVIRONMENT AND CONFIGURATION VARIABLES**
>
> The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, the `core.editor` configuration variable, the `VISUAL` environment variable, or the `EDITOR` environment variable (in that order).

You set `core.editor` with ...

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

Comment: No, I didn't miss them, but I wanted to change the editor everywhere, not just for git :)

Comment: I prefer nano so I used this
git config --global core.editor "nano"